# Multiple requestmapping value with path variables

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/abcd", "/employees/{value}/{id}"})
public String getEmployees(
      @PathVariable(value = "value") String val, 
      @PathVariable(value = "id") String id,
      @RequestParam(value = "param", required = false) String value) {
        // ********

}
```

For one url I am passing the path variable and for one I am not. But I want both the url to hit the same API. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 8):

You can now have optional path variables via support for Java 8 [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). At least Spring version 4.x will be required.

```
@RequestMapping({"/abcd", "/employees/{value}/{id}"})
public String getEmployees(
    @PathVariable("value") Optional<String> val, 
    @PathVariable("id") Optional<String> id,
    @RequestParam("param") Optional<String> value
) {
    // ********
}
```

N.B. this doesn't work with the optional primitives (`OptionalInt`, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

We can't have `optional path variables`, you can have two controller methods which can call the same service.

**First Method**

```
@RequestMapping("/abcd")
public String getEmployees(@RequestParam(value="param", required=false)String value){}
```

**Second Method**

```
@RequestMapping("/employees/{value}/{id}")
public String getEmployees(@PathVariable(value="value") String val, @PathVariable(value="id") String id, @RequestParam(value="param", required=false) String value){}
```

For `@RequestParam` we can use,

`@RequestParam(value="somevalue",required=false)`

for optional `params` rather than a `pathVariable`

Answer (score 5):

Just found a way to do this without using multiple methods.

First create a simple class to hold the path variables:

```
public class EmployeesRequest {
  private String value;
  private String id;

  public String getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Then define your controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value={
  "/abcd",
  "/employees/{value}/{id}"
})
public String getEmployees(@RequestParam(value="param", required=false) String param,
                           EmployeesRequest request) {
  if (request.getValue() != null) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Spring will automatically map any path variables available to the `EmployeesRequest` class.  Spring will also do this for any request parameters so you can simplify things further by adding the request parameter to `EmployeesRequest`:

```
public class EmployeesRequest {
  private String value;
  private String id;
  private String param;

  public String getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getParam() {
    return this.param;
  }

  public void setParam(String param) {
    this.param = param;
  }
}
```

And then finally:

```
@RequestMapping(value={
  "/abcd",
  "/employees/{value}/{id}"
})
public String getEmployees(EmployeesRequest request) {
  if (request.getValue() != null) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

An added benefit of this solution is that now you can support both variables or request parameters.  Meaning all of these would be valid:

- `/abcd`
- `/abcd?param=123`
- `/abcd?value=123&id=456&param=789`
- `/employees/123/456`
- `/employees/123/456?param=123`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found this solution:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/clients/page", "/clients/page/{page}"})
public Page<Client> index(@PathVariable Optional<Integer> page) {
   PageRequest pageRequest = page.map(integer -> PageRequest.of(integer, 4))
   .orElseGet(() -> PageRequest.of(0, 4));
      return clientService.showAll(pageRequest);
}
```

Intellij helped me to get this kind of compact result. Although Intellij throw this message:

''Reports any uses of java.util.Optional, java.util.OptionalDouble, java.util.OptionalInt, java.util.OptionalLong or com.google.common.base.Optional as the type for a field or a parameter. Optional was designed to provide a limited mechanism for library method return types where there needed to be a clear way to represent "no result". Using a field with type java.util.Optional is also problematic if the class needs to be Serializable, which java.util.Optional is not. ''

To be honest, I'm new in this business and I don't understand clearly what the IDE is telling me. If someone with more expertise could help to clarify that message would be great.